# page menu entry for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I've created a custom post type 'on this day'.
I know once created with the `has_archive` set to true I can directly access the archive url.

`http://my-url-example.com/on-this-day/`

When creating a menu entry for the custom post type, how do i associate the custom post type with a page of the same name? This is in a similar fashion to how any page can be associated with the blog-roll.

Thanks